# unpack() without for loop

Tags: perl, byte, unpack

In Perl I am using the [unpack()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) function to unpack binary data into bytes. So far I got this:

```
my $lenOverHead = 3;
my $lenWithoutOverheads = length($thing->{_raw}) - $lenOverHead;

my @AA;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $lenWithoutOverheads; $i++)
{
    push (@AA,  unpack('C', substr($thing->{_raw}, $lenOverHead+$i)));
}
```

Note that `$thing->{_raw}` is just a string with binary data.

Now the question is, is there a better(=more efficient)/nicer way to do this with `map()` or similar, without requiring a `for` loop?

I tried the following:

```
my @BB = map { unpack('C', $_) } substr($thing->{_raw}, $lenOverHead);
```

But of course it only unpacks the first byte, not all of them....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you were going for

```
my @AA = map { unpack('C', $_) } split //, substr($message, 3);
```

which can be optimized into

```
my @AA = map ord, split //, substr($message, 3);
```

But I would use `unpack`. The trick is that you can follow types with a number or `*` to indicate how many you want to extract.

```
my @AA = unpack('C*', substr($message, 3));
```

```
my @AA = unpack('x3 C*', $message);
```

```
my ($header, @AA) = unpack('a3 C*', $message);
```

```
my ($header, $body) = unpack('a3 a*', $message);
my @AA = unpack('C*', $body);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple solutions and explaining the available choices here

Comment: There's even `n/C` if the number of character prefixes the characters.